# Can't access a web page in Tor, but am able to in other browsers

Tags: configuration, error

I'm using Tor (v 6.0.6 (based on Mozilla Firefox 45.5.0)) on Mac Sierra.  I realize the behavior is largely unpredictable, but what are some possible reasons why requesting a page in a Tor browser woudl result in a 403 or "Unable to connect" message whereas it is easily accessible in a Chrome/Firefox browser?  An example is I'm never able to visit htis page -- http://www.plattsys.com/m1shell.asp?eventid=1080 , in a Tor browser and trying to think if there are any configurations I can make that would make my Tor browser behave more like the other browsers where I can access this page easily.

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: After reading this I'm clear on why companies block certain Tor IPs but my question is what can I do to access the web site in question.

Comment: Talk to the site administrator, make a case for allowing anonymous users to access it: https://blog.torproject.org/blog/call-arms-helping-internet-services-accept-anonymous-users

Comment: Not an option.  My quesiton remains, how do I trick the server into thinking it is dealing with a regular browser and not Tor?

Comment: You can't. The server would always be able to tell, some of Tor Browsers changes are hard-coded patches and will exhibit unique behavior and Tor exit relays gain better legal protections from being open and obvious about who they are.

Comment: "How do I use Tor to be anonymous *and* get special treatment at the same time", buddy, I got some news for you about anonymity...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try clicking on the Tor menu (or the onion, or whatever it's called) and click **New Tor Circuit for this Site**? (If that fails, try clicking **New Identity** to get a new circuit, clear browser state, etc. See https://blog.torproject.org/category/tags/new-identity for more details on that.)